# Subsetting data in a loop and write results to a list

Tags: r, loops, plyr, subset

I have dataframe containing five variables. Two of them are metric measurements and three of them contain groups stored as factors. I try to subset this dataframe three times in a loop by the different groups and calculate the mean of each metric measurement per group. The results could be stored as new dataframes within a new list. For now I used `subset` and `ldply` from the `plyr` package. A single subset is no problem but when I try to store the results from the loop in a vector I get a warning message stating that `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`. An example code can be found below. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
df<-data.frame(a=c(1:5),b=c(21:25),group1=c("a","b","a","a","b"),group2=c("b","a","c","b","c"),group3=c("a","b","c","d","c"))

# single subset
llply(subset(df,group1=="a")[1:2],mean)

# subset for all groups
# create grouplist
grouplist<-colnames(df[3:5])
# create vector to store results
output.vector<-vector()

# create loop
for (i in grouplist)output.vector[i]<-ldply(subset(df,grouplist=="a")[1:2],mean)

output.vector

Warning messages:
1: In output.vector[i] <- ldply(subset(df, grouplist == "a")[1:2],  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

so the output of one item in the list would look like this:

```
output.vector$group1
         |a|    | b|
|a|     |2.67|  |3.5|
|b|     |22.7|  |23.5|

output.vector$group2
     |a|    | b|    |c|
|a|  |2|    |2.5|   |4|
|b|  |22|   |22.5|  |24|

output.vector$group3
     |a|     |b|    |c|    |d|
|a|  |1|     |2|    |4|    |4|
|b|  |21|    |22|   |24|   |14|
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you want? (I'm not sure whether you're dividing by group1, group2, and group3, dividing within group1, or whatever)

Comment: of course. Please see the edits above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option in base package using `by` and `colMeans` , and looping through the group columns:

```
 id.group <- grepl('group',colnames(df))
 lapply(df[,id.group],
       function(x){
         res <- by(df[,!id.group],x,colMeans)
         do.call(rbind,res)
       })
$group1
         a        b
a 2.666667 22.66667
b 3.500000 23.50000

$group2
    a    b
a 2.0 22.0
b 2.5 22.5
c 4.0 24.0

$group3
  a  b
a 1 21
b 2 22
c 4 24
d 4 24
```

**EDIT** adding some benchmarking

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(ag(),dr(),an())

Unit: milliseconds
 expr       min        lq    median        uq      max neval
 ag()  4.717987  4.936251  5.072595  5.394017 27.13639   100
 dr() 14.676580 15.244331 15.689392 16.252781 43.76198   100
 an() 14.691750 15.159945 15.625107 16.312705 46.01326   100
```

Looks like agstudy solution is the winner , 3 times faster than the 2 other solutions!

Here the function used:

```
ag <- function(){
id.group <- grepl('group',colnames(df))
lapply(df[,id.group],
       function(x){
         res <- by(df[,!id.group],x,colMeans)
         do.call(rbind,res)
       })
}
dr <- function(){

grouplist<-colnames(df[3:5])
lapply(grouplist, function(n) 
  daply(df, n, function(d) colMeans(d[, 1:2])))
}


an <- function(){
temp <- melt(df, id.vars=1:2)
setNames(
  lapply(unique(temp$variable), function(x) {
    aggregate(. ~ value, temp[temp$variable == x, c(1, 2, 4)], mean)
  }), unique(temp$variable))
}
```

Comment: @Joshi I edit a little bit my answer, to avoid indeixng by number.

Comment: @agstudy, nice solution. I was trying to think of a `by` approach but it didn't come to mind.

Comment: @agstudy that's really cool.thank you. Is `plyr` somehow slow or only in this specific case? I used it in other functions and it always seemd to be a little slow...

Comment: `plyr` is definitely SLOW! maybe @Arun can suggest some `data.table` solution here.

Comment: @Joschi, `plyr` is not necessarily about performance, but rather trying to create a somewhat unified syntax for common operations.

Comment: @AnandaMahto This makes totally sense. It is actually very intuitive for me as a beginner to use `plyr` but when I used it with `cut` and `classIntervals` it took me like half an hour on a matrix with 38550 entries...but I'm not sure if it is because of plyr or the other ones...

Comment: @agstudy: Nice solution. The best `data.table` solution would be `m.dt = as.data.table(melt(df, c("a", "b"))); dt[, list(a=mean(a), b=mean(b)), by=c("variable", "value")]` (using `melt` from `reshape` package). Of course this wouldn't be the output format the OP wanted, but in my opinion it would actually be a better format to work with.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to convert your data to a long format first, and use `lapply` and `aggregate`.

Here's the data in a long form.

```
library(reshape2)
temp <- melt(df, id.vars=1:2)
temp
#    a  b variable value
# 1  1 21   group1     a
# 2  2 22   group1     b
# 3  3 23   group1     a
# 4  4 24   group1     a
# 5  5 25   group1     b
# 6  1 21   group2     b
# 7  2 22   group2     a
# 8  3 23   group2     c
# 9  4 24   group2     b
# 10 5 25   group2     c
# 11 1 21   group3     a
# 12 2 22   group3     b
# 13 3 23   group3     c
# 14 4 24   group3     d
# 15 5 25   group3     c
```

Here's the calculation. I believe all the calculations that you are interested in are there.

```
setNames(
  lapply(unique(temp$variable), function(x) {
    aggregate(. ~ value, temp[temp$variable == x, c(1, 2, 4)], mean)
  }), unique(temp$variable))
# $group1
#   value        a        b
# 1     a 2.666667 22.66667
# 2     b 3.500000 23.50000
# 
# $group2
#   value   a    b
# 1     a 2.0 22.0
# 2     b 2.5 22.5
# 3     c 4.0 24.0
# 
# $group3
#   value a  b
# 1     a 1 21
# 2     b 2 22
# 3     c 4 24
# 4     d 4 24
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using a combination of `lapply` and `daply` from the `plyr` package:

```
grouplist<-colnames(df[3:5])
lapply(grouplist, function(n) daply(df, n, function(d) colMeans(d[, 1:2])))

# [[1]]
#       
# group1        a        b
#      a 2.666667 22.66667
#      b 3.500000 23.50000
# 
# [[2]]
#       
# group2   a    b
#      a 2.0 22.0
#      b 2.5 22.5
#      c 4.0 24.0
# 
# [[3]]
#       
# group3 a  b
#      a 1 21
#      b 2 22
#      c 4 24
#      d 4 24
```

Comment: @Joschi: Sure thing. Latest edit improves it a bit as the matrix columns now have names along with the rows

Comment: thats cool. thank you! I edited your code a little bit because you had groupnames instead of grouplist inside the brackets...